# How to hide database password in C# and Sqlite security

Tags: c#, database, security, sqlite, passwords

I have just started developing a desktop application using C# and SQlite database (with sensitive information) that will be installed on any PC locally. I would like to store the database password and the sql commands somewhere safe. I have a some questions about this:

1. How much do you think is the SQlite database secure? I have read
   that by adding the encryption the whole file is encrypted, even the
   header. By How much do you think it is secure?
2. To store the password, there are a lot of choices (and some are maybe simple suggestions that I was thinking of): 
   a) Storing the password and the SQL commands in a dll file and obfuscating it. But has anyone tried before to crack this or searched for it using Olly Debugger for example?
   b) Encrypting it in the app.config file, custom encryption. But I've read a couple a articles and the encrypting connection string seems to be crackable...
   c) Putting the password in an XML file and encrypting it or maybe in a serialized file (But the encrypting will also be stored in a the source code and can be refracted).
3. If the application has been obfuscated and the database encrypted. Do you think there will be any performance issues?

Thank you.

Comment: bare SQLite doesn't encrypt the db, but there are some extensions that you may want to look into: http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html, http://sqlcipher.net/

Comment: Of course, I am not using the bare sqlite, I am encrypting it with SQlite Expert Professional or the dll provided by sqlite.org. I've tried opening the file in a text editor and it seems encrypted.

Comment: how do you tell that it is encrypted?  i think that a lot of times, it's difficult to tell by eye.  the encryption extension can do AES-256 in OFB mode, which is probably pretty good.  i think that see only ships as source, so if you get the dll, chances are that it is not built in...

Comment: and on #2, one practice that is done commonly is to not store the password at all.  instead, store a hashed version (hashed using a 1-way function like crypt or md5).  to validate, hash what the user enters and compare the hash.  this way, if someone manages to get a copy of the db and hack the initial encrytion, that person still can't quite recover individual passwords, yet.

Comment: #3, yes.  but whether it's enough to be a problem depends on your application and platform.

Comment: #2 The user doesn't enter any password, the password is just use to encrypt the database. I know it would be easier with hashing (Btw thanks a lot for helping)

Comment: And I've checked what the System.Data.SQlite uses as an encryption. And it is said here http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/473.aspx that it uses Microsoft Crypto API and the RC4 algorithm. I am not an expert in this. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself what is it exactly that you are trying to protect against and what for. Anything you can do in a purely client-installed application, especially a managed one, can be cracked quite easily. Dongles are more crack-proof, but will not stop an experienced cracker if the payoff is large enough, and they are both expensive and a pain in the ass for users and distributors. The only reliable way to protect your application is to run sensitive parts of it on your own servers. In your case, the database could reside on your server, then you can give out individual passwords, check IP addresses, limit query rates to deter scraping etc.

**OTOH** if your sole object is to protect your database against casual interest by persons having little technical knowledge, any scheme for database encryption and any scheme for password storage more complicated than plain text in the configuration file will work just fine.

Comment: What do you think about obfuscation? Can it be cracked easily too?

Comment: Obfuscation as such cannot be *cracked* (i.e. original identifiers cannot be recovered), but there is no need to. References to CLR assemblies and p/invokes cannot be obfuscated, and string/resource encryption schemes are next to useless. These provide the cracker with suffficient information to find passwords and/or remove protection from the obfuscated program.